# Is it possible to prevent js from executing (without browser extensions)?

Tags: javascript

I have such page structure:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script>
            //here sought-for script should go
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            //Here the example of the script, that should not be executed, goes
            var xmlHttp = null;
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://test.com/img.jpg", false );
            xmlHttp.send( null );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**The question is** - how can I prevent a script in `<body>` section from executing from within script in `<head>` section.

**Why do I need it?** I need to prevent some ads from loading **without** using any browser extensions (e.g. Adblock). Simple ad **hiding** using CSS **won't work**.

Any suggested solution may work. Any direction for digging will be appreciated.

**Important update**: I have access only to `<head>` section. xmlHttp stuff was written only as example. I need to prevent a single script in a `<body>` section from executing, regardless of its contents

Comment: You could edit your `hosts` file to point `test.com` at localhost. Won't stop the script, but it won't load an ad either. Alternatively, I guess you could redefine `XMLHttpRequest` as an empty function. Something as simple as `XMLHttpRequest = function() {}`

Comment: You could simply disable Javascript in your browser. That would cause all scripts to not execute, which might cause issues for some websites.

Comment: I need to do it using js **only**. I have no access to hosts or browser settings. @MattBurland well, I need to solve that task, not just delete it :)

Comment: @Shtirlits: And why doesn't removing `XMLHttpRequest` "solve the task". It'll stop the ad loading. Wasn't that the task?

Comment: From `script` tag that defined in `head` section is not visible `body` content, so it's unable to manipulate it. The only way is to use [`window.stop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.stop), thus prevent page from loading.

Comment: @MattBurland I need to prevent a single script in a `<body>` section from executing, regardless of its contents

Comment: @Shtirlits: Well, how else are ads loading? The general case isn't possible, unless maybe you wrap the page with another page that will load it via ajax and parse it before displaying it.

Answer (score 1):

You can override XMLHttpRequest definition on head, and rollback the override after execution of unwanted code.

Something like this should work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script>
            var originalXMLHttpRequest = XMLHttpRequest;
             XMLHttpRequest = function(){
                  this.open = function( a,b,c ){
                      //do nothing
                   };

                   this.send =function(a){
                      //reset definition
                      XMLHttpRequest  = originalXMLHttpRequest ;
                   };
             }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            //This script should not be executed
            var xmlHttp = null;
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://test.com/img.jpg", false );
            xmlHttp.send( null );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the first ajax will be ignored, and after this the normal XMLHttpRequest will be restored, you can change this logic to accomplish your needs

Comment: Thanks for your response. Updated a question to be more clear about what I need to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Scripts are executed as they are encountered. Period.

But your question is somewhat confusing. You have enough control over the page to inject your own script into the `head` element, but cannot control what is coming into the `body`?

Do you want to disable all body scripts, or just that particular one? If it's just that one, it's easy enough---

```
<script>
    xmlHttpRequest = function () { };
</script>
```

The calls to `open` and `send` will error out, but who cares.

Comment: I have access only to `<head>` section. xmlHttpRequest was written only as example. I need to prevent a single script in a `<body>` section from executing, regardless of its contents